# 'Proxy Connect ABORTED' error behind Proxy accessing GitHub

Tags: proxy, curl, github, http-proxy

Our proxy server is giving a Connection ABORTED error when connecting to GitHub. GitHub is on the allow list. Any tips for the networking team? Could this be a problem with cURL?

```
ubuntu@ip-10-xxx-xxx-xx-xx:~$ git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
Cloning into 'vcpkg'...
00:32:13.943853 http.c:695              == Info: Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
00:32:13.963521 http.c:695              == Info:   Trying 10.xxx.xxx.xx...
00:32:13.963543 http.c:695              == Info: TCP_NODELAY set
00:32:13.970662 http.c:695              == Info: Connected to myproxy.mydomain (x.x.x.x) port 1080 (#0)
00:32:13.970695 http.c:695              == Info: allocate connect buffer!
00:32:13.970709 http.c:695              == Info: Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to github.com:443
00:32:13.970748 http.c:642              => Send header, 0000000111 bytes (0x0000006f)
00:32:13.970762 http.c:654              => Send header: CONNECT github.com:443 HTTP/1.1
00:32:13.970776 http.c:654              => Send header: Host: github.com:443
00:32:13.970788 http.c:654              => Send header: User-Agent: git/2.17.1
00:32:13.970801 http.c:654              => Send header: Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
00:32:13.970821 http.c:654              => Send header:
00:32:13.980658 http.c:695              == Info: Proxy CONNECT aborted
00:32:13.980674 http.c:695              == Info: CONNECT phase completed!
00:32:13.980685 http.c:695              == Info: Connection #0 to host myproxy.mydomain  left intact
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the proxy protocol is http, not socks5.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).